# Why getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath() doesn't work in final product after compiled?

Tags: java

Ok, Here is my Web project. I built it in eClipse with the following structure:

```
workspace3\MyProject\war\images\uploaded
workspace3\MyProject\war\WEB-INF\classes
```

Ok, I want to store the uploaded images into `workspace3\MyProject\war\images\unloaded`, so here is the code at service side & it works fine in Eclipse

```
String absolutePath = getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
absolutePath=absolutePath.replace("WEB-INF/classes/", "images/uploaded");
File file = File.createTempFile("upload-", "."+extName, new File(absolutePath));
```

Ok, now I compiled my project & put it into VPS with Tomcat server and it has the following structure

```
tomcat7\webapps\ROOT\images\uploaded
tomcat7\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\classes
```

However, somehow when run the website via internet, it couldn't find the `images\uploaded` location.

Did i do anything wrong here? 
Why `getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath()` doesn't work in final product after compiled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should rather use [`ServletContext#getRealPath(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath(java.lang.String)) to determine the file system path of your web application:

```
String absolutePath = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/images/uploaded");
// File uploaded to this directory will be accessible via
// `http://<yourserver>/<web-app>/images/uploaded/`
```

But be careful! The servlet specification does not guarantee, that `getRealPath` will return a path to a writable directory. And it may return `null` in case the virtual path cannot be translated to a real path!

If you want to be sure, that the destination is a writable directory, and you just want to upload files into a temporary directory for processing, consider using the [web application's private temp directory](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#TEMPDIR):

```
File tempDir = (File)request.getServletContext().getAttribute(ServletContext.TEMPDIR);
// Files uploaded to that directory will NOT be automatically published to WWW.
```

Note that this directory is temporary only and may not survive a server restart! So it is not thought for durable persistance.

The most sensible and durable solution is to write the file into a database, or any other repository (e.g. [JCR](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=283) like [Jackrabbit](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/)), or into a file directory that is NOT controlled by your web server (and is specified from outside, e.g. via system property or in `web.xml`).

Comment: do i need to do anything in web.xml?

Comment: if doing correctly then when opening mydomain.com/images/uploaded/pic1.png will show an image

Comment: @Tum no, you don't have to change web.xml for that, and yes, the first solution will make your uploaded image available to the web as described.